# Do ghouls receive Feeding Ground bonus when being subjected to Predatory Aura on regnant's territory?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, vampire-the-requiem-2e

Feeding Grounds (VtR2e 112):

> Feeding Grounds (• to •••••)
>
> Effect: Your character has fertile feeding grounds, whether officially granted or not. Dots in this Merit represent the ease of hunting in that territory. Add the dot rating to any hunting rolls, and to starting Vitae rolls (see p. 95). In addition, add the dot rating to any predatory aura conflicts on her territory.
>
> Drawback: Territory doesn’t maintain itself. Trespassers must
> not go uncontested, or your hold on the area falters.

Lashing Out mechanic is described on VtR2 page 92. It doesn't mention Feeding Grounds at all.

Merit's description says "any predatory conflicts in her territory". Does it apply to ghouls?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, because the ghoul doesn't have the Feeding Grounds merit, their regnant does. As a rule of thumb, any advantage described in a merit only applies to the person who bought it.

However, it wouldn't break the system to let it work that way, as a house rule. Ghouls are at a significant disadvantage in Lashing Out because they don't have Blood Potency. Allowing them to offset that in their master's territory won't seriously unbalance anything.